# Duvida sobre métodos e classes Python

Tags: python-3.x, classes, método

Eu tenho a classe Login e criei uma instancia dela na classe Main, com a instancia eu estou chamando o método iniciar, porém no método iniciar ao clicar no botão 'Logar' não é executado o método 'show_entry_fields' corretamente. Ao executar e clicar a classe Main eu recebo de imediato no console: 'login errado' . Ou seja, não sei porque, mas está executando direto o 'else', sem que eu precise clicar no botão.(o if não está sendo executado). Alguem pode ajudar ou explicar o que fiz de errado? Segue o código de ambas as classes

```
from tkinter import *


class Login:

    @staticmethod
    def show_entry_fields(nome, senha):
        if nome == 'admin' and senha == 'admin':
            master.destroy()
        else:
            print('login errado')

    @staticmethod
    def iniciar():
        master = Tk()
        Label(master, text='Usuário').grid(row=0)
        Label(master, text='Senha').grid(row=1)

        e1 = Entry(master)
        e2 = Entry(master)

        e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

        Button(master, text='Sair', command=master.quit).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
        Button(master, text='Logar', command=Login.show_entry_fields(e1.get(), e2.get())).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)
        mainloop()
```

classe Main:

```
 from FechaLogin import Login

 g = Login()
 g.iniciar()
```

Comment: Depois de colar o código auqi, sempre use o botão `{}` para fotmatar o código corretamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro pude notar que sua classe Login está muito bagunçada, tem código para definir a interface aqui e ali.

Segunda coisa que notei, e te recomendo a não fazer é usar `import tkinter *`, já que isso torna o código menos legível, além de poder causar problemas de `namespace`.

Depois de recriar, usando como base o que você colocou de seu codigo o resultado a que cheguei foi esse:

```
import tkinter as tk

class InterfaceLogin(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.master = master
        # Cria Botões para Login e Sair
        self.btn_login = tk.Button(self.master, text='Login', command=self.check_login_info)
        self.btn_quit = tk.Button(self.master, text='Sair', command=self.master.destroy)

        # Texto que é exibido antes da caixa, indicando o que deve ser informado
        self.lbl_usuario = tk.Label(self.master, text='Usuario: ')
        self.lbl_senha = tk.Label(self.master, text='Senha: ')

        # Entrada para Login e Senha respectivamente
        self.entry_login = tk.Entry(self.master)
        self.entry_senha = tk.Entry(self.master, show='*')

        # Posiciona os Botões, Entradas de Texto e Labels na janela usando grid
        self.btn_login.grid(row=3, column=0)
        self.btn_quit.grid(row=3, column=1)

        self.lbl_usuario.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.lbl_senha.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.entry_login.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.entry_senha.grid(row=2, column=1)

   # Função responsavel por validar o Login e Senha digitado
   def check_login_info(self):
       # Usa get() para recuperar as informações digitadas pelo usuario
       usuario = self.entry_login.get()
       senha = self.entry_senha.get()

       if (usuario == 'admin') and (senha == 'admin'):
            print('Login realizado com sucesso.')
       else:
            print('Erro ao realizar o login.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    janela = InterfaceLogin(root)
    janela.mainloop()
```